# Access api variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, api, javascript-objects, console.log

I am trying to access varaibles in the object returned by an API but it's inside of another object "0" in this case

Screenshot of console
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H33De.png)

JavaScript code

```
    fetch('https://dad-jokes.p.rapidapi.com/random/joke', options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            document.getElementById("joke").innerText = (response.body)
            })
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

I can't write console.log(response.0.setup) and console.log(response.body.0.punchline) because JavaScript won't let me. How would i access the setup and punchline from JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an API key to test this out myself, but it sounds like you can solve this with [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors). Any object property can be accessed like `object['property']` which is equivalent to the dot notation `object.property` for properties with string names. In this case your property is named with a number so the bracket notation is the only way to access it.

This should achieve what you're trying to do

```javascript
document.getElementById("joke").innerText = (response[0])
```

and you can chain off of that to access the setup and punchline like

```javascript
const punchline = response[0].punchline
```